# HTML 5 Local Storage File Path

Tags: html

I need to be able to a file from the HTML 5 local storage in the browser. Is it possible to point a URL to a file in the HTML 5 local storage?

Answer (score 2):

No. HTML 5 local storage is not accessible as files — for instance, in Google Chrome, each site's local storage exists on disk as one SQLite database file per domain, but other web browsers may implement it differently.

If you need your application to store media locally, and/or to be accessible offline, [HTML5 application caching](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) is going to be a better option.